# Relating independent/dependent sets, spans and generating sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking a linear algebra class and I can't keep up. I am having trouble relating all these concepts together no matter how many times I reread all the chapters covering these topics.

I know that a matrix is a representation of a system of equations. But how does nullity and rank play into the variables, free variables and inconsistency or consistency of a system of equations?

What does dependence mean for a span?

From what I understand a span is based on the rank of the matrix and that a span is the set of all numbers that can be generated by a combination of the columns. But I am not sure how to visualize this, why it is important or what it means.

The nullity I can kind of understand, it is related to if the equation is solvable or not.

A generating set I am not sure of, I know the list of requirements for something to be a generating set but I just can't figure out what it means, what it is and how to actually find one without memorizing all the conditions that my books lists.

What about independence and dependence?  How does all of that fit into this, I know that if the vectors in a set rely on eachother to be a solution it is dependent otherwise it is independent and they don't. But what does this mean? What does it look like on a graph? Why is this important?

I can do row operations and all of that but I just can't make sense of the concepts and how they all relate, I am falling behind in my class and I find that the lectures are just mechanical run throughs of row operations and I am not learning. Can anyone help me relate these concepts to each other? I have read the chapters a dozen times but I just don't understand it.

Comment: Your question is very long and seems to necessitate a long answer. If you aren't understanding the book or your lectures you could try watching videos from Strang's lecture series at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/. Lecture 6 might be a good place to start.